# Generics propagation in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a Java code with quite tricky generics propagation scenario:

```
public class Main {

  public static void parent(Parent<String> parent) {}

  public static void child(Child<String> parent) {}

  public static <T> Parent<T> makeParent() {
    return new Parent<>();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this works
    parent(makeParent());

    // this works
    Parent<String> objectParent = makeParent();
    child(objectParent.child());

    // this works
    child(Main.<String>makeParent().child());

    // this does not work
    child(makeParent().child());
  }

  static class Parent<T> {

    public Child<T> child() {
      return new Child<>();
    }

  }

  static class Child<T> {}

}
```

1. I am curious why and how this works `parent(makeParent());`? How replacement for T is inferred?
2. And also why this does not work `child(makeParent().child());`? As the same generic type is propagated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to remember about type inference in call chains is that the type inference is done as you move along the chain: if you have `a().b()`:

- Type inference is run for `a()` first;
- Then a type is inferred for `a().b()`

So:

1. `parent(makeParent())`: the type of `makeParent()` is inferred according to what is compatible with the parameter of `parent()`. Since that will only accept a `Parent<String>`, that's the inferred type.
2. `child(makeParent().child())`: the type of `makeParent()` is inferred; but there are no constraints on the type (it's not the parameter to the outer `child`), so it's inferred to be `Parent<Object>`; then the type of `makeParent().child()` is `Child<Object>`, which isn't compatible with the parameter type of `child`, hence the compiler error.

It's annoying that Java doesn't defer the type inference of `makeParent()` until it has more information, namely the fact that `makeParent().child()` has to be compatible with some particular type.

I suppose this is done to limit the complexity of the inference: I can imagine a situation where some obscenely complex set of type inference constraints could need to be solved.